# "liner: function not supported in this terminal" when doing personal.newAccount()

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts

In the `geth` console I am trying to add an account :

`> personal.newAccount()`

but I am getting the following error :

> liner: function not supported in this terminal

What does this mean and how do I fix it.

***Note:*** I am running my node via the docker container

Answer (score 3):

The [code for this](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/vendor/github.com/peterh/liner/fallbackinput.go) error has a comment that says :

```
// PasswordPrompt is not supported in this OS.
```

I suspect that the docker container setup doesn't allow passwords to be typed in.
This issue can be avoided by providing the password parameter:

```
> personal.newAccount('myNewPassword')
```